# Terraform proxyconnect error

Tags: terraform

With version 0.11.7 of Terraform when I run `terraform init` I'm getting:

```
[ERR] Checkpoint error: Get https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform?arch=amd64&os=linux&signature=9cb67b37-446e-c9cc-b9b8-953644a81a2d&version=0.11.7: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup https on <corporate dns ip>:53: server misbehaving
```

Any suggestions on what the problem is (other than our DNS server is misbehaving!) and how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

This is related to their checkpoint service: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/tree/master/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/go-checkpoint

You can disable by running:

```
CHECKPOINT_DISABLE=1
```

Checkpoint itself can be entirely disabled for all HashiCorp products by setting the environment variable CHECKPOINT_DISABLE to any non-empty value.